# Web services invocation from mobile devices

Tags: web-services, ipad, rest, mobile, sencha-touch

We are developing a dashboard application. In the home screen it has four charts and list view. The data for these charts and list view are stored in different tables in the backend database. We are planning to create web services for fetching the data from server. 
My question is, do we need to write separate web services (in this case 5 web services) for fetching the data or can we create a single web services that returns all the data in a single call?

If we write different services, then we need to invoke five services from the mobile device (iPad/Android Tablet). If we write single service, the response time will be delayed due to the joining table in the server side.

We are creating our application using Sencha touch framework. Our app is a cross platform mobile application. The web services are writing using restful wcf services and it returns JSON.

Please give ur your suggestions

Comment: You can do it either way. Generally, a join will be faster than separate network calls, but YMMV based on DB indexes, table sizes, etc.

Comment: But in our case, the data are different. We need to write five separate queries for fetching the data from DB.